Convergence of binomial random variables
Random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are independent and for each $n \ge 1$, $X_n$ has distribution $\operatorname{Bin}\left(n, 1/n\right)$.
a) Show that $\limsup_{n\to \infty}X_{n} = \infty$ a.s.
b) Show that $\left(X_{n}\right)^{1/n}$ is convergent in $L^{p}$.
I'm stuck in both questions:

In a) I've tried using Borell-Cantelli or Poisson approximation, but without luck.
In b) I don't even know how to start, since computing expected value seems very difficult.

Any hints would be appreciated.

for b) $\mathbb{E}|X_n^{\frac{1}{n}}- 1|^p = \sum_{x=1}^{n} |x^{\frac{1}{n}} -1|^p \frac{n!}{(n-x)!x!}(\frac{1}{n})^x (\frac{n-1}{n})^{n-x} \leq |n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1|^p\sum_{x=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{(n-x)!x!}(\frac{1}{n})^x (\frac{n-1}{n})^{n-x} \to 0$
This is the general method, feel free to comment on it

Thank you! Point b) wasn't that hard, I didn't think about such an easy bound. As for point a) I'm still struggling. I don't see how I can calculate this probability and any bounds from below lead to the converging series :(

Edited with solution

Why $\mathbb{P}(X_n \ge n/2) = \frac{1}{2}$?

Sorry this is incorrect, I’ll have another look at it next week
